# Matching regular expression custom validation

Tags: javascript, regex

For my personal project i tried to create a validator with Regex but i have been struggling.

here is what i want the valid token to look like.

```
const valid = '12gehuwguhwefhdlewofewy';
```

should startstart with a number.

```
  function token(validation){
return \d[0-9][aA-hH].match(validation)
}
```

Comment: `[aA-hH]` is not what you think it does. Should be ranges with just one character at each side of the hyphen. You can do `[a-hA-H]`. Don't forget to delimit your regex with `/`.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the pattern? Should the hyphens appear exactly where they do in your example?

Comment: You say *"should not accept letters above t"*, ... then why you have `h` in your regex?

Comment: Are you looking for [`^\d[a-s\d]{7}-([a-s\d]{4}-){3}[a-s\d]{11}$`](https://regex101.com/r/n3wgjE/1) ?

Comment: Try this `^\d[a-s0-9]{7}-[a-s0-9]{4}-[a-s0-9]{4}-[a-s0-9]{4}-[a-s0-9]{11}` if you need it in the same structure (it looks like a guid)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
^\d[a-tA-T\-0-9]{34,}$
```

Check here: [here](https://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/140)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`^\d[\da-t-]{34,}$`

This covers following condition:-

- Length must be equal to 35 or greater.
- String should start with a number.
- String should contain character only up to t.
- This includes `-` in test

```js
let str = `5c763j12-b752-32c1-cas3-54h7csae76e`
let str2 = `Ac763j12-b752-32c1-cas3-54h7csae76e`
let reg = /^\d[\da-t-]{34,}$/gi

console.log(reg.test(str))
console.log(reg.test(str2))
```